# Android In-App Billing: Title and Description displayed where?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

After giving my Managed Product an id tag (or whatever it's called), it asks for a Title and Description.

Is this displayed to the user at some point? If so, where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user will see the name of the purchase when your app will launch the purchase workflow and popup will appear asking user if they want to make a purchase.
You may also choose to show the user title and description of the purchase when you get in-apps from the server but it's up to you.
I think user may also get a receipt with the purchase name.
[image]